# TinyMCE remains hidden (uvw-dialog-open)

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

Ok i've developed a nice tinymce-solution, where i create and destroy all the tinymce-instances programmatically through js - so, i know it is maybe not the daily-usage of a tinymce implementation - but basically it works like a charm.

Now, before i will give you specific example code - i will explain my strange issue: A friend of me is an extreme power-user of the online-tool i made and he is creating/destroying hundrets of tinymce-instances during the day...

Sometimes, after hours of work, he has the behavior, that tinymce won't show up when he hit "edit"-button. I never made it, to reproduce that on my own - but one day, in a teamviewer-session, i was able to have a look into his screen and page (with firebug), when the error already happened.

So, badly i was not able to make a full debugging through the javascript-code (because when you hit one times f5 in this situation, the error disappears and it will take some other hours to get it again) -> i realized, that, when the error was happened -> everything in the tinyMCE-object itself seems ok -> also everything in the DOM-rendering seems ok -> BUT, from some strange css-import-file, there was suddenly a definition like this:

```
html.uvw-dialog-open object, html.uvw-dialog-open iframe, html.uvw-dialog-open embed {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is causing that a main-panel of tinymce won't show and nothing of tinymce is visible anymore.. killing and recreating of the instance won't fix the bug in this moment, you must press f5 and after a reload, you even can't find this css-definition again (or, at least, i was not able over teamviewer and his shitty, small laptop)

So, the only thing that came in mind was an ugly hack in my own css, telling this:

```
html.uvw-dialog-open object, html.uvw-dialog-open iframe, html.uvw-dialog-open embed {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

And, since then... it was quite for weeks -> but today, my friend calls me again, telling me, that he can't see tinymce, AGAIN.. i was almost in tears, you can imagine :D

Ok.. after writing and re-reading all these lines -> i realize that my fix won't work... both are the same definitions and if they appear on the same level (file, not inline).. probably last-match-wins i guess, what would be the newly, lazy loaded tinymce-file.. so it will definitly be better, to make an inline visibility:visible; over the init_instance_callback of tinymce...

But, in my desperation, i thought i will write everything down here on stackoverflow -> maybe someone knows the real cause of this issue and.. you guys are the most awesome devs out there i know :D

Answer (score 2):

Jebbie,

Thoughts more than a definitive answer ...

Sounds like a memory leak issue due to lots of javascript/DOM activity in a long-lifed page.

You've probably done nothing wrong and you're unlikely to track down the actual cause, however certain measures are available to you :

- Try making your tinymce instances reusable rather that destroying and creating new every time.
- Periodically have the page request a re-serve - it may be a challenge to reproduce the entire document state - DOM and javascript environment - in the re-served page.

Lots of work and no guarantees I'm afriad.

Comment: nice, thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts - the first point is a great argument.. till now i never thought about to re-use my instances, and i think.. when it is a mem-leak and i think you're right in that point, this approach would be the best way to avoid it.. the second point, i guess i don't understand what you actually mean :D

-> currently i made a nasty hack; in the init_instance_callback i'm going to add an inline "visibility: visible" with a delay of 100ms, so this should override definitely the "wrong" css in the file-import in that moment

Comment: Jebbie, the second point rephrased ... Take measures to reduce the life of the page, For example, every (say) 30 user interactions or on the first interaction after every (say) 15 minutes, arrange for javascript to refresh the page. In itself this is simple BUT you need to ensure that the current state of the DOM (what's showing and what's not) and of the javascript environment (variables, objects and closures) are recreated in the refreshed page. Recreation of page state may be quite involved unless someone knows of a simple, reliable technique.